# How to make switchable layers in the Leaflet L.Control.Layers always visible?

Tags: leaflet

I am developing a web mapping application with Bootstrap 4. I would like the Leaflet map to show in the left column and the Layers control to show in the right column (this means the Control is outside the Map container). Also the layers in the control should always be visible rather than in the popup pane.

See the image for the plan. All the switchable layers should stay in the blue rectangular area.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

Use the `getContainer()` method to get the html element, and append the element to an existing DIV that you would like the layers control to be in.

```
var htmlObject = layerControl.getContainer();
var a = document.getElementById('divLayers');
function setParent(el, newParent)
{
    newParent.appendChild(el);
}
setParent(htmlObject, a);
```